# Subclipse doesn't show the repository path next to projects

Tags: eclipse, path, repository, subclipse

Since updating the subclipse plugin the paths next to project name in Eclipse disappeared. There is no change after reverting the update.

When checking out a new project from repository, the brackets appear but are empty and after a while disappear too. Did I miss a configuration? Updating, commiting and reverting of project works fine.

---

*UPDATE*: 
Updating, commiting etc only worked because there was another implemantation of SVNKit. Removing this solved the problem for new projects checked out, but all workingcopies seemed to lost their connections. There is no point in context menu "Team -> Share Project" as written in docs, only an "Apply Patch" option is shown for my working copies.

Thanks @Ray Toal for surporting with this issue

Comment: Not a good question for StackOverflow.  Should be migrated somewhere.  But if you need to know: Eclipse -> Preferences -> Team -> SVN -> Label Decorations -> Text -> Project Format

Comment: sorry, if I'm wrong here with this, I saw some other eclipse related questions here. The preference shows: {dirty_flag}{name} [{url_short}], should be right..

Comment: Yes that does look right.  What do you see in the preview window?

Comment: Project [trunk/project1]

Comment: And in your **Package Explorer** window you see no label decorations after the project name at all?  Are you sure the project is open?  Sorry if a dumb question but I am out of ideas, that should work.  How about removing that, hitting Apply, then opening the dialog, putting it back in, and hitting Apply again.

Comment: I already did this.. Yeah in the _Package Explorer_ there is nothing, as if no svn repo is connected or something like that.

Comment: Try to check out a _new_ project from SVN, then, as a last try. Look for errors in the SVN console.  Other than that, I'm out of ideas.  Sorry.

Comment: OK, checking out fixed it for the new project. But for my working copies the connection seems to be gone. Even Team -> Share Project isnt available, only Apply Patch.

Comment: updated question with solution which worked for me

Comment: it is acceptable to create an answer with this information and even accept it.

Comment: but for the creater only 8 hours after submitting the question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed my problems by doing follwing steps.

- remove old subversive data which effects subclipse
- building a new workspace
- importing old projects into the new workspace

after doing that, subclipse recognises the .svn and can connect the workingcopies with the repository. Maybe there are more ellegant ways of archive that, but it works fine for me.

*Lesson learned*: **FIRST** disconnect projects from subversive **SECOND** remove *all* subversive data **THIRD** installing subversive and see how good it works.